# Using Swift 4's Decodable protocol for nested JSON server response

Tags: swift, swift4, codable, decodable

I am trying to implement Swift 4's new Decodable protocol and having some hard time approaching it.

This is my JSON server response:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Succcess",
  "data": {
    "name": "Logan Howlett",
    "nickname": "The Wolverine",
    "image": "http://heroapps.co.il/employee-tests/ios/logan.jpg",
    "dateOfBirth": 1880,
    "powers": [
      "Adamantium Bones",
      "Self-Healing",
      "Adamantium Claws"
    ],
    "actorName": "Hugh Jackman",
    "movies": [
      {
        "name": "X-Men Origins: Wolverine",
        "year": 2009
      },
      {
        "name": "The Wolverine",
        "year": 2013
      },
      {
        "name": "X-Men: Days of Future Past",
        "year": 2014
      },
      {
        "name": "Logan",
        "year": 2017
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

What would be the best approach to Decode the `data` part of the response?
Also, what happens if the `data` is suddenly an `array` instead of an object, how can I support both data types?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: `Also, what happens if the data is suddenly an array instead of an object, how can I support both data types?` — use `enum`s with associated values in your type? One case with `array`, other with `dictionary`.

Comment: You should read through [Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) in the Codable documentation to see how to write types that mirror your JSON representation. Mostly this involves writing the type and conforming to Codable, and the rest should be done for you.

Comment: For those who follow. Another good read (https://medium.com/swiftly-swift/swift-4-decodable-beyond-the-basics-990cc48b7375)

Answer (score 3):

First you can create an extension as a helper:

```
extension Data {
    func decode <Generic: Codable> () -> Generic? {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let object = try? decoder.decode(Generic.self, from: self)
        return object
    }
}


extension Dictionary {
    func decode <Generic: Codable> () -> Generic? {
        let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self,
                                               options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
        guard let d = data else {
            return nil
        }
        return d.decode()
    }
}
```

Then you can create a protocol to help you to build your objects:

```
protocol Encode: Codable {
    init(with dictionary: [String: Any])
    init(with data: Data)
}
```

with a default implementation:

```
extension Encode {
    init(with data: Data) {
        let object: Self? = data.decode()
        guard let obj = object else {
            fatalError("fail to init object with \(data)")
        }
        self = obj
    }

    init(with dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        let object: Self? = dictionary.decode()
        guard let obj = object else {
            fatalError("fail to init object with \(dictionary)")
        }
        self = obj
    }
```

Then create your objects as struct which conform to y `Codable` protocol. It will look like:

```
struct User: Codable {
    var name: String?
    var nickname: String?
    ...
    // If needed declare CodingKey here
    // enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    //     case date = "dateOfBirth"
    //     ...
    // }
}

struct Movies: Codable {
    var name: String?
    var year: Int?
}
```

Now you need to extract your dictionary of data from your response and to apply your new init methods:

```
if let dic = json["data"] as? [String: Any] {
    let user: User = User(with: dic)
    // Do stuff here
}
```

If data become suddenly an Array, you will have to handle it differently (as an array of User in this example)

Comment: Please explain in comment why my answer is not appropriate so I could replace or improve it. Thanks

Comment: I have no idea who downvoted your answer, but it wasn’t me. I will read it tomorrow morning and try it. Will let you know how it went :)